# Как получить имя нажатой Nodes в TreeView?

Tags: .net, c#

Я создаю TreeView.

```
TreeView tv = new TreeView();

tv.Parent = this;
tv.Nodes.Add("gio");           
tv.Nodes.Add("rezi");
tv.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("0");
tv.Nodes[1].Nodes.Add("1");
tv.Nodes[0].Nodes[0].Nodes.Add("111");
panel1.Controls.Add(tv);
tv.Click += new EventHandler(trv);

public void trv(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
    string ggg = ((TreeView)obj).Text;
}
```

Но не получается: что-то не доделываю.

Comment: tv.SelectedNode.Text - что-нибудь в этом роде должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

((TreeView)obj).SelectedNode.Text